# Hide some elements in a Spinner

Tags: java, android

I have a class containing a private `boolean`, and an `ArrayList`. I want to populate a `Spinner` with the elements inside my `ArrayList`, but if the `boolean` is true I want to show all the elements, otherwise I wish to hide some elements in a range. I tried the following:

```
Spinner modeSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_setup_mode_spinner);
ArrayList<String> modeList = enc.getModes();
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, modeList);
modeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
modeSpinner.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
if(!boolean){
    for(int i=4;i<8;i++){
        modeAdapter.remove((String) modeAdapter.getItem(i));
        modeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But it does not work. Which is the correct way to do this? 
**Update:** Working code

```
Spinner modeSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_setup_mode_spinner);
ArrayList<String> modeList = enc.getModes();
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, modeList);
modeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
modeSpinner.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
if(!boolean){
    for(int i=4;i<modeList.size();i++){
        modeAdapter.remove(modeList.get(i));
        modeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove from adapter not adapter strings, but object that you early add into it.

Try this: modeAdapter.remove(modeList.get(i));

Comment: It works though I have to init the ArrayList every time. (getModes is accessed staticly) I also had to change the for loop.